# Google Translate API v2 403 error on server - not from 2 dev boxes

Tags: google-translate

Using a Server API Key from 2 different dev boxes and Google Translate works fine. On the server I get the following error:

```
{
    ...
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
}
```

I have added the Server IP to the list of approved IPs. I have tried using a browser key as well to no avail.

Comment: Did you add one IP address per line, try CIDR mask? Maybe just paste in (and of course, you can obfuscate) what you have in your IP address list -- and if you haven't tried it yet, isolate just your server IP as the only IP address in the list.  Lastly, if you are on a server that has multiple internet IP addresses (e.g. virtual ethernet interfaces) you need to know which one is accessing the the Google API.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. It got me down a path that solved the issue. I ended up adding the IPV4 and IPV6 addresses in and bingo, it worked!